# How to configure a useable screen locker in Awesome+LightDM+NixOS?

Tags: nixos, awesome, lightdm, lightdm-gtk-greeter, light-locker

I've been using Awesome+LightDM with the [GTK greeter](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/blob/f09393c529a3226ba5db7566f13e2bc9ab1f17ef/modules/greeter/manifests/init.pp) on Arch Linux for some years, and I'm in the process of moving to NixOS. One issue with this has been the screen locker. I've [mapped <kbd>Windows-l</kbd> to `light-locker-command --lock`](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/blob/15d146ec69422f626b2f60ef5b5827dd43ec4839/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L357-358). When activating that the screen goes black, then turns off. To get back to LightDM I have to press <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F7</kbd> and wait for about 10 seconds while some weird message about "being redirected to the unlock dialog" displays. I've tried installing and enabling both the "gtk" and "mini" greeters (not at the same time), but after restarting X neither of these seem to be used. How do I set either of them up?

The relevant part of the [configuration](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/blob/e8bb1b3b3bfd8e6fd2cfa973045939ac69730c9f/configuration.nix):

```
services = {
  xserver = {
    displayManager.lightdm.enable = true;
    enable = true;
    layout = "us";
    libinput.enable = true;
    windowManager = {
      awesome.enable = true;
      default = "awesome";
    };
    xkbOptions = "compose:caps";
    xkbVariant = "dvorak-alt-intl";
  };
};
```

I also tried enabling `programs.slock`, but that doesn't integrate with lightdm.

Comment: Please add your xserver configuration from `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`.

Comment: The gtk greeter is enabled by default. Note that "installing" greeters don't have any effect on NixOS. Instead you must enable them via their corresponding NixOS modules. Say you want to use the mini greeter, have you tried disabling the gtk greeter and enabling the mini greeter? To be honest, I have no idea what happens when multiple greeters are enabled.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa The original question wasn't clear, but I never did try to enable both greeters at the same time. I just don't get why none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a [locker](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/commit/ccd5543d79197ae19620a656b6396b97b65e6125):

```
services.xserver.xautolock.enable = true;
```

, install xlockmore, then [use it](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/commit/4f02fb2ae6f97cebf15d4adc79d0734dd0f0e3a6):

```
awful.key({ modkey }, "l", function () awful.spawn("xautolock -locknow") end,
          {description = "lock the screen", group = "client"}),
```